"> Task (...) :app: FAILED" in Android Studio
I'm trying to update an Android app without any documentation so it's being really tricky. After doing lots of changes I always get the same error and I don't understand it or why it happens. It occurs when I click on play button to run the app on the emulator:
:app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:checkDebugAarMetadata
:app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths
:app:processDebugMainManifest
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses
:app:desugarDebugFileDependencies
:app:mergeDebugNativeLibs
error
I can't run the app or export the bundle with those errors.
My build.gradle file (project level) looks like this:
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://repo.spring.io/release"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://repository.jboss.org/maven2"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2'
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

and my settings.gradle file like this:
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
        maven {url 'https://jitpack.io'}
        jcenter()
    }
}

include ':app'
include ':liveVideoBroadcasterSDK'

rootProject.name = "oxoo-tv"

I changed these two files a lot but the error remain the same from the beginning.

Please [edit] your question to also add the full error message/stacktrace from the logs.
